# Managing transactions of dynamically created objects in spring

Tags: spring, oop

I have a web service which receives a data object(Let's call the class Student). At the web service, I wrap it using a StudentWrapper object as follows

`new StudentWrapper(student)`

and I want the `StudentWrapper` class to have methods such as `save` which would save the data to the database. I want to use the spring framework to annotate the `save` method so that it will run within a transaction. But then the StudendWrapper object would have to be a spring bean(defined in XML). If it is a spring bean, then I won't be instantiating it as I have shown above.

My question is how can I make the StudentWrapper a Spring bean (so that I can use Spring annotations to manage the transactions) but pass the Student object (that I receive over the web service) in to the StudentWrapper?

If there are any other suggestions that would help me in solving this problem, please share them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to create the object using a constructor, make the `StudentWrapper` `@Configurable` and read up about using AspectJ to create prototype bean definitions for domain objects (section 9.8 of the reference manual.)

A simpler alternative, if you don't want to go with AspectJ but don't want a direct dependency on Spring is to encapsulate the prototype bean creation in a factory. I'll show you using JavaConfig, though you can do something similar in XML.

First the student object...

```
package internal;

public class Student {

    private String name;

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{name='" + name + "'}";
    }
}
```

And now the wrapper object...

```
package internal;

public class StudentWrapper {

    private Student student;

    public StudentWrapper(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StudentWrapper{student='" + student + "'} " + super.toString();
    }
}
```

And now the factory,

```
package internal;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class StudentWrapperFactory {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public StudentWrapper newStudentWrapper(Student student) {

        return (StudentWrapper) this.applicationContext.getBean("studentWrapper", student);
    }
}
```

And now the JavaConfig, equivalent to an XML configuration

```
package internal;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "internal")
public class FooConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public StudentWrapper studentWrapper(Student student) {
        return new StudentWrapper(student);
    }
}
```

Finally the unit test...

```
package internal;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {FooConfig.class})
public class FooIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private StudentWrapperFactory studentWrapperFactory;

    @Test
    public void foo() {

        Student student1 = new Student("student 1");
        Student student2 = new Student("student 2");

        StudentWrapper bean1 = this.studentWrapperFactory.newStudentWrapper(student1);
        StudentWrapper bean2 = this.studentWrapperFactory.newStudentWrapper(student2);

        System.out.println(bean1);
        System.out.println(bean2);

    }
}
```

produces

```
StudentWrapper{student='Student{name='student 1'}'} internal.StudentWrapper@1b0fa7ff
StudentWrapper{student='Student{name='student 2'}'} internal.StudentWrapper@20de643a
```

As you can see from the object references of StudentWrapper, they're different prototype beans. `@Transactional` methods should work as expected in `StudentWrapper`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Emerson! After reading your answer and the spring documentation that you have mentioned, I was able to achieve what I wanted.